# AppDesigner/Add-On-Explorer unusable under Linux

Tags: matlab

*I know that this question is not only related to Matlab, but I'm asking how to implement a specific workaround in Matlab.*

I'm running Matlab (2019a, Update 3, but this also happend in 2018b) on a Lenovo P52 with SuSE Leap 15.0. It has two graphic cards, an onboard Intel card and a Nvidia card:

```
$> lspci -nnk |grep -EA 3 "VGA"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3e9b]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:225f]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1cba] (rev ff)
    Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
70:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:225f]
```

As you can see, I'm using the Intel card.

Matlab runs fine with this setup, until I'm running `appdesigner` or the Add-On Explorer (or any of the components from the `Apps`-Tab in the main window). The contents of the `appdesigner`-window only appear if I change the window's size, and any changes are only displayed after a resize (there might be other possibilities to force the contents to show up, but I haven't figured them out).

I guess all these components internally use the chrome browser. The native (that is, not shipped with Matlab) chrome browser shows (nearly) the same behaviour on my system. However, it throws an error when started:

```
$> chromium
[32273:32273:0703/095509.613762:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
```

Obviously, this problem is not related to Matlab. However, if I start `chrome` with the `--disable-gpu` flag, it works as expected.

The Malab-related question is: Is there any way to tell Matlab to call its internal chrome with this flag?

Comment: Have you tested whether or not the [`opengl`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/opengl.html) settings affect this?

Comment: Uh, no, I didn't. Using `hardwarebasic` seems to make `appdesigner` and friends usable. This seems to be an answer, I'd be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many rendering issues I've had, if they couldn't be helped by [updating drivers](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/resolving-low-level-graphics-issues.html) and such, could usually be fixed by adjusting the [`opengl`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/opengl.html) settings. Assuming it has defaulted to [`hardware`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/opengl.html#bug2yed-1-hardware), you could try setting it to either [`software`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/opengl.html#bug2yed-1-software) or [`hardwarebasic`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/opengl.html#bug2yed-1-hardwarebasic) (a stripped-down set of graphics features) and see if that helps.

...and don't forget you may need to [save the new settings](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/opengl.html#bug2yed-1-pref) for future sessions:

```
opengl('save', 'hardwarebasic');
```

Comment: As already said, `hardwarebasic` works. `software` is not support for linux.

Comment: @PatrickHappel: The docs are a little confusing on that point. The command `opengl software` does not appear to be supported, but [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/opengl.html#bug2yed-1-software) sates that you can set it at startup using the `-softwareopengl` flag.

Comment: Yes, starting with the flag works. Should have be more precise: "...switching to `software` is not supported for linux"

Comment: After your edit regarding the saving: If I test for [deep peel transparency](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/opengl.html#buwqe0q-1) by using `figure, sphere, ax=gca, ax.Children(1).FaceAlpha = .5, view(-30, 65)` I get different results for limited and full hardware suport (as I expected). Thus, a permanent change of the `opengl` settings is not a good idea, and changing the settings at all is a workaround, but not  a true solution.

Comment: @PatrickHappel: It is, of course, all dependent on what your needs are. If this is a consistent problem you have every session and don't want to keep changing it, saving the preferences is a way to go. If it is only something that affects one piece of code, you can just change the setting when running that. I simply mentioned the extra option for anyone else with similar issues.